# Does gunicorn thread take more ram memory?

Tags: gunicorn

I built redirect system.

gunicorn --workers=5 --threads=30 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 "app:create_app()" --error-logfile /home/ubuntu/error.log

It was my option to start gunicorn app.

After checking my htop,

[image]

It seems each thread takes some amount of RAM (3.3%).

When the app reaches the maximum RAM, does it stop producing new thread?

How can I wisely control the proper number of threads? And How can I block when it takes too much RAM like over 95%?

Comment: You are creating 5 workers with up to 30 threads each. If each is taking 3.3% of memory you have committed about 5 times your entire memory.

I don't know the specific implementation but programs almost never deal with running out of memory well.

I think you need to set more reasonable limits on your system yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to control that with gunicorn or os ??

Comment: I do not think so. It would be odd to write a program and tell it to use all of your memory.  Just change your max threads to 5. It seems like all your system can handle.  Having more won't help if the system can't keep up with them.